# Gradle build fails thanks to 'fatJar task' although code worked for me in another project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I tried to create a fatJar with Gradle. I found a good example on this [site](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/) that worked well for me in another project. In my recent project an error occurs during the 'gradlew build' task, namely the following:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
>   Build file 'D:\dev\MarkPublished\build.gradle' line: 40
>
> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'markpublished'.
>   Could not find method Attributes() for arguments [{Implementation->Title=Gradle Jar File, Implementation-Version=1.0-Snapshot, Main-Class=path.classname}] on root project 'myproject'.

This is my (shortened) 'build.gradle'-file:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'idea'
}

group 'mygroup'
version '1.0-Snapshot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

idea {
    ...
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

repositories {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        Attributes ('Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'path.classname')
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with Jar
}
```

I use Win7 and IntelliJ Idea 14.1.5.

Honestly, I absolutely have no clue and I wouldn't ask here if it didn't already work for me in another project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to make a fatJar task as:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'path.classname'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with Jar
}
```

Attributes must be in lowercase, like `attributes`.

Comment: Corrected my issue

Answer (score 1):

To create a spring-boot jar artifact :
1) insert the following code at the very beginning of your build.gradle file (1st line):

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
 }
 dependencies {
   classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE'
 }
}
```

2) The jar name is determined by settings.gradle file:
    rootProject.name = 'commons-ex1111'

To generate the spring-boot application jar in inteliJ, trigger the 'bootJar' task on the GRADLE window, or simply write 'gradle bootJar' on the command line.

Jar will be created under: \build\libs

The entire build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "1.2.3"
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'ex1.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}
```